# Magento 2.2.3 Vat-Id Field not showing Shipping or Billing Address

Tags: forms, vat, billing

I have enabled the Show Vat number option in the frontend, but the Vat-Id field is only displayed on the sign-up form. I can not add the VAT number on the shipping or billing address forms on the checkout page.